# Unable to fetch all contacts using lookup key

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am not able to fetch all the contact numbers saved under a person using `LookUpKey`. I have saved three contact numbers under one person(home, mobile and work). But when i query the contacts using a contact's lookUpKey it is not fetching all the saved contacts.

This is my code

```
ArrayList<ContactItem> contactItems = new ArrayList<>(5);
String lookUpKey = params[1];

Uri dataUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
Cursor dataCursor = mApplication.getContentResolver().query(dataUri,
        null,
        ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY + " = ?",
        new String[]{lookUpKey}, null);
if (dataCursor == null || !dataCursor.moveToFirst()) return contactItems;
M.logE("cursor length = " + dataCursor.getCount());
M.logE("column count = " + dataCursor.getColumnCount());

ArrayList<String> tempContacts = new ArrayList<>();

String homePhone;
String mobilePhone;
String workPhone;
while (dataCursor.moveToNext()) {
    final String data2 = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE));
    final int contactType = dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2));
    M.logE("Contact type = " + contactType);

    if (!data2.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
        continue;
    }

    if (contactType == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        mobilePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA_1));
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mobilePhone)) continue;
        mobilePhone = mobilePhone.replace("-", "");
        mobilePhone = mobilePhone.replace(" ", "");
        if (!tempContacts.contains(mobilePhone)) {
            tempContacts.add(mobilePhone);
            contactItems.add(new ContactItem(mobilePhone, "Mobile"));
        }

    } else if (contactType == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME) {
        homePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor
    .getColumnIndex(DATA_1));
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(homePhone)) continue;
        homePhone = homePhone.replace("-", "");
        homePhone = homePhone.replace(" ", "");
        if (!tempContacts.contains(homePhone)) {
            tempContacts.add(homePhone);
            contactItems.add(new ContactItem(homePhone, "Home"));
        }

    } else if (contactType == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK) {
        workPhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor
    .getColumnIndex(DATA_1));
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(workPhone)) continue;
        workPhone = workPhone.replace("-", "");
        workPhone = workPhone.replace(" ", "");
        if (!tempContacts.contains(workPhone)) {
            tempContacts.add(workPhone);
            contactItems.add(new ContactItem(workPhone, "Work"));
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong in this? How can I fetch all details using a `lookUpKey`?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't consider all the options for a Phone type, there are other possibilities other than mobile/home/work.

Second, you have a lot of "continue"'s on that code, each can be the culprit, I suggest you change the query a bit to replace the first check for `CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE` by querying on Phone., and then just dump the cursor to the log and manually check if you see all the phones you expect to see.
Other then that, the query looks ok.

```
String[] projection = new String[] { Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE };
String selection = Phone.LOOKUP_KEY + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {lookUpKey};

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
DatbaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);
cursor.close();
```